# SQL Server simplify long queries involving repeated date calculations

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a query that involves calculating income for a period of 6 months. The difficulty is that the starting and ending dates can be any day of the month. For example, I might have a table like this:

```
MyTable
Year    Month    Income    
2011       01      38.9
2011       02      30.5
2011       03      55.2
2011       04      28.3
2011       05      33.6
2011       06      36.3
2011       07      41.8
2011       08      43.7
...
```

Let's say that I know the starting date is `2011-02-09`. Then the ending date would be `2011-08-09` for 6 months. To calculate income during this period, I have to prorate the numbers in both Feb and Aug of 2011 using the starting and ending days. This makes my query look like this:

```
SELECT [Year],
  [Month],
  CASE(
    WHEN [Year]*12+[Month] = YEAR(start_date)*12+MONTH(start_date)
      THEN -- prorate 1st month
        Income*(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), 
                DATEDIFF(
                    dd, 
                    DATEADD(dd, 1-start_date, start_date),
                    DATEADD(mm, 1, start_date)
                )/DATEDIFF(
                    dd, 
                    DATEADD(dd, 1-DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, start_date)), start_date), 
                    DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(start_date), start_date)
                )
                )
    WHEN [Year]*12+[Month] = YEAR(start_date)*12+MONTH(start_date)+6
      THEN -- prorate last month
        Income*(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), 
                DATEDIFF(
                    dd, 
                    DATEADD(dd, 1-DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date), DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date)),
                    DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date))
                )/DATEDIFF(
                    dd, 
                    DATEADD(dd, 1-DAY(DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date)), DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date)),  
                    DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date)), DATEADD(mm, 6, start_date)
                )
               )
   ELSE
     Income
   ) AS ProratedIncome
FROM MyTable
...
```

Note that I get the starting date from another table with a join.

In my actual problem, I have more branches involved than what this example shows. As you can see, it gets very prolonged and cumbersome. So my question is, is there a way in SQL that I can simplify this kind of code to make it readable to avoid potential bugs?

I did research about user defined functions, but was not able to come up with an easy and clean way to simplify this.

Comment: Do you have another table that contains income by day instead of the one that is aggregated by month?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, No. That's why I am doing proration.

Answer (score 0):

Why not build a table that does all the proration in a CTE:

```
WITH Proration AS
(
Table would look like
#|NumOfDays|Proration Amount|
#|1| 0.42|
#|2| 0.84|
# etc....
)
```

Then just do the calculation and JOIN on the CTE with the number of days

If the calculation still becomes complex even after you build the logic into a CTE or #Temp table. Push it into another temp table and keep chopping up the problem into smaller issues.

Hope this makes sense. I'm not even going through your logic to convert, just in general a better approach may be to break this problem up.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah this could work -- make a table of month year for each month and year in range and then a pro-rate column of 0 - 1.0 of percent.  Then join to this table and just multiply by this column.  if it is 1 no pro-rating -- a percent then you get the value.